# Having trouble understanding Prolog DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

[image]

[image]

This is a new following up question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170191/confused-about-how-to-use-in-prolog?noredirect=1#comment56112107_34170191

I tried to make the code in 9.7 more powerful. So I decide to add a new grammar

```
every,man,that,a,woman,loves,dance
```

the answer should be

```
all(man(X)&exists(woman(Y)&loves(Y, X)))->dance(1)))
```

at least I believe it is the answer.

I tried some approach but it does not work. This is my final Wrong solution:

```
rel_clasue(X,P1,P3)-->[that],determiner(X,P1,P2,P3),noun(X,P1),trans_verb(X,P2,?).
```

? means that I do not know what to write.
and I believe I has other bugs too.
Rest code are exactly as book above. 
of course I add "dance" part

Can some one help me fix it or write a correct one?

Comment: & is in the first picture. And I never go that far to write query, because i failed to finish the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `rel_clause//3` it looks like you basically have two rules: an empty base case and another case that accepts a verb phrase. So it works when you give it `[that,loves,a,woman]` for instance:

```
?- phrase(rel_clause(X, P1, Y), [that,loves,a,woman]).
Y = P1&exists(_G1990, woman(_G1990)&loves(X, _G1990))
```

But it doesn't work when you give it a more complex phrase:

```
?- phrase(rel_clause(X, P1, Y), [that,a,woman,loves]).
false.
```

So I think you need to add a rule to `rel_clause//3` to handle that. It seems clear to me that `[that,a,woman,loves]` and `[that,loves,a,woman]` is really just inverting the relationship, and in the former case we actually get a transitive verb without a noun following it to be the direct object. In other words `[that,a,woman,loves]` is somehow like `man(M) & (exists(woman(W)) & loves(W, M)` where `[that,loves,a,woman]` is more like `man(M) & (exists(woman(W)) & loves(M, W)`, where the M and W are swapped in the `love/2` structure.

I venture this as a guess:

```
rel_clause(X, P1, (P1&P3)) -->
    [that], noun_phrase(Y, P2, P3), trans_verb(Y, X, P2).
```

This seems to produce the parse we want:

```
?- phrase(sentence(X), [every,man,that,a,woman,loves,lives]).
X = all(_1, man(_1)&exists(_2, woman(_2)&loves(_2, _1))->lives(_1)) ;
```

Apart from that, `dance` should be `dances` and you will need to make an intransitive verb rule for that:

```
intrans_verb(X, dances(X)) --> [dances].
```

Comment: Thanks! But i still cannot let my code work. So i send you an email. I hope it is ok. BTW,I get you email from your personal stack overflow page.